# "Undefined reference to" Error while linking object files

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, g++

I realize this question has been asked in a number of ways including [this very comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) but I have looked at many and tried fixing my error to no avail.

I am using .cpp and .c files to create a program. I compiled all files with g++,  it seemed to have no more linking errors, though it gave me a bunch of C++ errors related to the C syntax. This was the command I used:

```
g++ -o program main.cpp /data/*.c -l[...libs]
```

The main.cpp calls functions in the .c files.
I then understood that one should not try to compile both .c and .cpp files with one compiler, instead to use gcc for one, g++ for the other, and thereafter to simply link the object files.

So I did this (the .c files are part of a library, and already have .o files)

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -o program main.o /data/*.o -l[..libs]
```

But then here I will get "undefined reference to" errors for functions called from main.cpp to the precompiled .c files, errors which I didn't get previously.

Could anyone help? Or do I maybe need to provide more information?

EDIT (a more in depth excerpt of code, I've tried to simplify otherwise this will be impossible to read, but let me know if I still need to add stuff, I'll try to remove unnecessary code):

main.cpp :

```
#include "header.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string s1 = argv[2];
    fn1(s1)
}
```

header.h

```
void fn1(string s1)
```

mycfile.c

```
#include "header.h"

void fn1(string s1){
    fprintf(stdout, " you entered %s", s1);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

ANSWER:

@Smeehey helped me figure out the solution, it was actually that I was still including the old headers in an .hpp file I was using. But the core solution was indeed to use the external C{}.

Comment: Please post your code, normally undefined ref error is caused when including header files to some code hence getting references to functions / variables and not linking the actual code of the actual functions / definitions

Comment: Order of arguments to `g++` matters a big lot, even order of libraries. Be more specific. Also, **always** pass `-Wall -g` to `g++`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is highly likely to do with C-vs-C++ linkage. In your `main.cpp`, you probably have something like this:

```
#include <data/header.h>
```

where `header.h` refers to your c library. Replace it as follows:

```
extern "C" {
#include <data/header.h>
}
```

This tells your c++ compiler not to use c++-style name mangling when defining the required symbols from the header, allowing the linker to successfully find them in the c-compiled `.o` files.

Comment: Just to clarify on this, if I have a function `fn1( string st1)` , which is defined in a .c file, declared with an `include header.h` in my .cpp file, and i DON'T use `extern C`, when I check the `nm -u` I will get something like `U _Z16fn1iPPcP7String`. while if i DO use `extern C`, I should get something like `U fn1`?

Comment: When running `nm` on your *c++* compiled object file - yes, that's right.

Comment: Yes on the C++ .o file. hmm that might be the cause of the issue then, even after I add the 'extern C' i still get the mangled name

Comment: Can you post your full code, command lines, and linker error?

Comment: I could do that but it's currently very large and unwieldy (main.cpp is 450 lines) since I've yet to clean it up... The command line is `g++ -Wall -v -std=c++11 -c src/main.cpp -o main.o -I include/ -I /usr/include/gpac/applications/dashcast/`

Comment: In main I have: `extern "C" {
  #include <cmd_data.h>
  #include <controler.h>
}   int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  dc_parse_command(argc, argv, &cmd_data);
  dc_run_controler(&cmd_data);
  dc_cmd_data_destroy(&cmd_data);}`

Comment: And the the sourcecode for dashcast is [here] (https://github.com/gpac/gpac/tree/master/applications/dashcast)

Comment: And which symbol from the header files is still mangled according to your `nm -u` output?

Comment: All 3 of those commands

Comment: Are you getting this issue with your example code or your actual code? I can trivially show that mangling is removed in my own version of the example code. Your example code couldn't possibly work (with `extern "C"`) as you pass a `string` to your function `fn` which I assume is an `std::string` - but this couldn't work in a `extern C` header as its a c++ template (unless you used some non-trivial trickery)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120137/discussion-between-victor-dmdb-and-smeeheey).

Answer (score 2):

You have to compile C files with the `gcc` command, C++ files with either `gcc` or `g++`, and link with the `g++` command. This sequence will probably work:

```
 gcc -c data/*.c main.cpp
 g++ -o program *.o -l <libs...>
```

Next step: learn to write proper makefiles.

Comment: Using `gcc` (instead of `g++`) to compile C files seems to work.  Then link with `g++`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark but the problem might be the way C and 
Cpp files are compiled is simillar yet slightly different....
Due to name spaces the function `foo` would generate the symbol `some_prefix@foo`
Unlike C whereas `goo` generates the symbol `goo`

Try doing the following in your .cpp files

`extern "C"
{
 #include "yourcfilesheader.h"
}`

And please attach your code